# Rails and MySQL connection fails only on a particular query

Tags: mysql, ruby, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rails 3.2 Ruby 1.9 app using MySQL 5.5 on an Ubuntu 13. The app has a 'login' screen as a starting point and then a menu based system which brings up further web pages with data from the database.

I can login and move around all of the system except for ONE page where the query fails. This is due to MySQL saying that the connection parameters are not valid for that particular user. i.e. the user or password are incorrect.

Exact message:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I also cannot directly login to MySQL as follows:

```
mysql -uroot -p<password>
```

This produces the same error.

EDIT: Lalit's question below prompted me to include the relevant section of database.yml here:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2

  encoding: utf8

  reconnect: false

  database: gi_development

  pool: 5

  username: root

  password: <pwd>
```

So my question is how come MySQL connection works via the app, except for the one query, whilst it wont allow me to login to MySQL using the same parameters as the connection?

EDIT: To resolve the problem I ended up resetting the password for the 'root' user on the database by logging in without the grant tables and then restarting MySQL.  Now I can login as well as run the ONE report too.

So clearly there was a problem with the password but the question still remains, why did it work elsewhere within the app?

Comment: So... What is the query? And what is in your database.yml? (obviously, censor the password)

Comment: @Amadan whilst I used the word 'query' it is actually a method call which brings together various bits of data from different tables as an array.  The main point is that the connection fails for this method but doesn't for all others.